# Loading data for an Activity as soon as application starts

Tags: java, android

How can I begin loading data for my activity as soon as my application starts? At the moment, I have it set up to download information needed as soon the the main screen is launched - which is where the user must login. Depending on the connection speed and how quickly the user logs in, the data may not be loaded and causes issues when the activity is launched, because the data hasn't been loaded. (The `spinner` won't have any data, etc.)

I currently have two `AsyncTask` - one for the login, and one to download the data. Once the user leaves the screen, it seems as though the `AsyncTask` stops. I tried putting a timer to wait until a `boolean` variable is set to `true` from the task which downloads the data, but that seems to force close the application. Here is an example:

```
while (!settingsLoaded) {
   SystemClock.sleep(1000);
}
```

When the AsyncTask that downloads the data hits the `onPostExecute`, I set `settingsLoaded = true`. Should I be using something else to download the data?

**Note** -- when the application is launched, I do `task.execute();` for the application data `AsyncTask`, and the other `AsyncTask` which logs in the users is set off dependent on whenever the users hits the 'login' button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, you don't mention what kind of data is being loaded - but from your description of scenario I would suggest you do something in the region of:

1. User starts the application
2. The Login-screen is shown
3. User enters name/pass and hits "Login"
4. AsyncTask to handle login is fired - A `ProgressDialog` is shown meanwhile.
5. Login task finishes - the Main Activity is started.
6. The data loading AsyncTask is fired - A `ProgressDialog` is shown while data is being loaded
7. Data loading finishes, `ProgressDialog` dissappears and the user can start using the app.

---

What most likely happens in your scenario is that the Login task finishes before the Data loading task. The way you do it at the moment you have no way of telling which task finishes first.

If you want to start data loading right away, you could do it using a `Service` and then having the Main Activity show a `ProgressDialog` when it starts, if the `Service` is not done loading yet.

Answer (score -1):

You should not start activity that requires unavailable downloaded data before async task with download completes. For better user experience you should show some kind of splash screen with process dialog (downloading...) to let user know about unfinished background process.

Comment: If possible, I'd like the data (for the spinners) to be loaded in the background. I'm trying to make it easier and quicker for the user, and pre-load information before they need it. I already have multiple other places where the user must wait and is greeted with a 'downloading..' dialog.